# Problem with deploying matlab simulink mode to Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, matlab

I encounter a problem when deploy matlab simulink model to Arduino UNO

Following shows the error

```
*The call to realtime_make_rtw_hook, during the after_make hook generated  the following error:
The build failed with the following message: The system cannot find the path specified
The build process will terminate as a result.
The build failed with the following message: The system cannot find the path specified。
Component: Simulink | Category: Block error*
```

When type >> getenv('path')

```
ans =

C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;E:\MathWorks\runtime\win64;E:\MathWorks\bin;E:\MathWorks\polyspace\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\polyspace\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\
```

I did not see anything wrong with the path. I tried to solve the problem following the "http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/168555-what-does-the-path-in-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-refer-to". However it does not work.

Anyone know how to solve it?

OS:Win8.1 Matlab 2014b 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your MATLAB shortcut and click "run as administrator". See if helps. Then do all the necessary steps and see if it happens again.

Also test with x86 version. I have seen lots of these kinds of error with x64 version. Always had compiling related issues with MATLAB x64 and Simulink!